# A plane that goes through two points and is parallel to player.transform.forward

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, plane

I've got a player with a sword and the two points on a target are from OnTriggerEnter and OnTriggerExit. Then I want to create a slicing plane that is parallel to player.transform.forward - it can be vertical, horizontal or on an angle (parallel to the player forward - which is always horizontal).

To define the plane I need its normal/up vector and one of the two points and it is infinite. So I'd like code for the plane's normal based on position1, position2, and player.transform.forward.

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: I used the following though I'm not really sure what is going on in it:

Vector3 sliceUpVector = Quaternion.FromToRotation(Vector3.left, sliceEndPos - sliceStartPos) * Vector3.up;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on LoïcLeGrosFrère I did this: (EzySlice also has a Plane class)

```
UnityEngine.Plane plane = new UnityEngine.Plane(sliceStartPos, sliceEndPos, playerPos);

SlicedHull hull = objectToSlice.Slice(sliceStartPos, plane.normal, crossMat);
```

An alternative:

```
public Vector3 GetPlaneNormal(Vector3 a, Vector3 b, Vector3 c)
{
    return Vector3.Normalize(Vector3.Cross(b - a, c - a));
}
Vector3 planeNormal = GetPlaneNormal(sliceStartPos, sliceEndPos, playerPos);

SlicedHull hull = objectToSlice.Slice(sliceStartPos, planeNormal, crossMat);
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you want achieve (cut a target with the player sword ?), you can use your two points and the "shoulder" of the player to create your slicing plane with [Plane.Set3Points](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Plane.Set3Points.html)